# Android error: Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an error in my android xml file.

```
error: Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token).
```

My xml code is:

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="105dp" 
        android:background="@drawable/white"

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" 
            android:lines="6" 
            android:minLines="6" 
            android:gravity="top|left" 
            android:maxLines="10" 
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:hint="Comments on my post"
        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Dunno if it's typo or not, but it seems that you missed out `>` after `android:background="@drawable/white"` and `android:hint="Comments on my post"`

Comment: @Neenu : Use `android:hint="Comments on my post" >` instead of `android:hint="Comments on my post"` before you are not ending EditText

Comment: it's your master layout or sub layout @NeenuJose111

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the following namespace and closing bracket (>) in your `RelativeLayout`.

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

So, add them to the `RelativeLayout`...as follows...

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="105dp" 
    android:background="@drawable/white">
```

You are also missing closing bracket (`>`) of `EditText`...Add that closing bracket as...

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine" 
    android:lines="6" 
    android:minLines="6" 
    android:gravity="top|left" 
    android:maxLines="10" 
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:hint="Comments on my post">
```

Then `Clean` and `Build` your project.

Answer (score 1):

you should close your RealtiveLayout like the following :

```
 <RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="105dp" 
        android:background="@drawable/white">


    ....


    </RelativeLayout>
```

and please give me feedback

Hope that Helps .

Comment: Thankyou for remind me the mistake. i corrected it.i build the project again.though the error notification is there that is ,error: Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token).

Comment: please post your full layout

Comment: @ Amrola.Finally everything set..thanks now no errors

Answer (score 1):

Corrected layout is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="105dp" 
android:background="@drawable/white" >

<EditText
 android:id="@+id/editText1"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:ems="10"
 android:inputType="textMultiLine" 
 android:lines="6" 
 android:minLines="6" 
 android:maxLines="10" 
 android:scrollbars="vertical"
 android:hint="Comments on my post"
 <requestFocus />
</EditText>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Forget to close `<EditText>` tag by `>` before calling `<requestFocus />`. change xml as:

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="105dp" 
        android:background="@drawable/white"
    >
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" 
            android:lines="6" 
            android:minLines="6" 
            android:gravity="top|left" 
            android:maxLines="10" 
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:hint="Comments on my post" >  <<---close EditText here
        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
 </RelativeLayout>
```